# How do I use this format of JSON in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

This is the JSON and controllers im using:

JSON Format:

```
       {"networks":[{"longName":"lo"},{"longName":"eth0"}]}
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('networkFactory', [ '$http', 
                                    function($http) {
                                        return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/JAXRS-RESTEasy/rest/toolservice/network")
                                            .success(function(data) {
                                                return data;
                                            }).error(function(err) {
                                                return err;
                                            })
                                        } ]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('networkController', [ '$scope', 'networkFactory',
                                        function($scope, jsonFactory) {
                                            jsonFactory.success(function(data) {
                                                    $scope.network = data;
                                    });
                                }]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="networkController">
   <table class="table">
     <tr ng-repeat="x in network">
            <td>{{x.longName}}</td>
     <tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

So i tried this, and the names don't appear they seem to not get loaded into the html.

What I'm I doing wrong, is the word "networks" in front of the JSON affect the way i need to read the JSON?

Thank you.

Comment: Found the solution, I used `ng-repeat="x in network.networks"` instead of `ng-repeat="x in network"`

Comment: you can modify $scope.network=data.networks instead of network.netwroks. That is a good approach to follow always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/x0zCgzNGggBueBFlg0H5?p=preview

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])
app.factory('networkFactory', [ '$http', 
                                    function($http) {
                                        return $http.get("tag.json")
                                            .success(function(data) {
                                                return data;
                                            }).error(function(err) {
                                                return err;
                                            })

                                        } ]);


                                        app.controller('networkController', [ '$scope', 'networkFactory',
                                        function($scope, networkFactory) {
                                            networkFactory.success(function(data) {
                                              debugger
                                                    $scope.network = data.networks;
                                    });
                                }]);
```

Comment: Plz mark it accepted so that others find it useful thank you, and increases your reputation.

Comment: `success` and `error` methods are deprecated, don't use them.

Comment: Instead then method can be used.